# I get a ClassCastException in java when I ask for the length of one array, how can I solve the problem?

Tags: java, classcastexception

When I ask for the length in the test I get an error with the casting of the integer, I tried with other classes like Character instead of Integer but I get the same error, java does not let me write Object or Comparable as parametrized classes.

**That's a JUnit Test Case**

```
public class EDBinaryHeapTest {
    @Test
    public void constructorTest01() {
        EDBinaryHeap<Integer> toCheck = new EDBinaryHeap<Integer>(0);
        
        assertEquals(0, toCheck.numElementos);
        assertEquals(0, toCheck.elementos.length); 
    }
}
```

**That's the class I`m creating to check**

```
 public class EDBinaryHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements EDPriorityQueue<T>{
    protected T[] elementos;
    protected int numElementos;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public EDBinaryHeap(int numMaxElementos) {
        elementos = (T[]) new Comparable[numMaxElementos];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few problems here:

1. You can't initiate `Comparable`.
2. Your `T` class extends `Comparable` and not vice versa.

To solve this you can use:

```
    elementos = (T[])Array.newInstance(type, size);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael, however I only can change the JUnit Test case due to the constructor was given by my teacher... Sorry because I didn`t explain it...